# Botón flotante en swift5 compatible con iOS 13, Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

necesito insertar un botón flotante en la parte inferior derecha de la pantalla que funcione con swift 5, que sea compatible con iPhone y iPad.

Alguna información actualizada de cómo poder implementar esto en IOS 13, Xcode 11.
Gracias.

Comment: Hola Luis, las preguntas pidiendo código o ayuda con depuración, deben incluir una descripción de lo que se está intentando hacer, un resumen de lo que se ha intentado (incluyendo código a ser posible) y los problemas/dificultades que se estén encontrando. Visita el [tour] y lee [ask] para más información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré una solucion que ha sido util para mí. Es bastante sencila de implementar y cumple con mis requerimientos:

- Video:
  https://youtu.be/xArCnGGzZEE
- Proyecto:
  https://github.com/yogeshpatelios/Swift-4---Easy-way-to-create-Floating-Action-Button-in-iOS-Application-Hindi..

La solución pasa por agregar los 2 archivos al proyecto (ActionButton.swift, ActionButtonItem.swift).

Archivo ActionButton.swift

```
import UIKit

public typealias ActionButtonAction = (ActionButton) -> Void

open class ActionButton: NSObject {

    /// The action the button should perform when tapped
    open var action: ActionButtonAction?

    /// The button's background color : set default color and selected color
    open var backgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 238.0/255.0, green: 130.0/255.0, blue: 34.0/255.0, alpha:1.0) {
        willSet {
            floatButton.backgroundColor = newValue
            backgroundColorSelected = newValue
        }
    }

    /// The button's background color : set default color
    open var backgroundColorSelected: UIColor = UIColor(red: 238.0/255.0, green: 130.0/255.0, blue: 34.0/255.0, alpha:1.0)

    /// Indicates if the buttons is active (showing its items)
    fileprivate(set) open var active: Bool = false

    /// An array of items that the button will present
    internal var items: [ActionButtonItem]? {
        willSet {
            for abi in self.items! {
                abi.view.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
        didSet {
            placeButtonItems()
            showActive(true)
        }
    }

    /// The button that will be presented to the user
    fileprivate var floatButton: UIButton!

    /// View that will hold the placement of the button's actions
    fileprivate var contentView: UIView!

    /// View where the *floatButton* will be displayed
    fileprivate var parentView: UIView!

    /// Blur effect that will be presented when the button is active
    fileprivate var blurVisualEffect: UIVisualEffectView!

    // Distance between each item action
    fileprivate let itemOffset = -55

    /// the float button's radius
    fileprivate let floatButtonRadius = 50

    public init(attachedToView view: UIView, items: [ActionButtonItem]?) {
        super.init()

        self.parentView = view
        self.items = items
        let bounds = self.parentView.bounds

        self.floatButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        self.floatButton.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(floatButtonRadius / 2)
        self.floatButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        self.floatButton.layer.shadowRadius = 2
        self.floatButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
        self.floatButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        self.floatButton.setTitle("+", for: UIControlState())
        self.floatButton.setImage(nil, for: UIControlState())
        self.floatButton.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor
        self.floatButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 35)
        self.floatButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 8, right: 0)
        self.floatButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.floatButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.floatButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ActionButton.buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.floatButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ActionButton.buttonTouchDown(_:)), for: .touchDown)
        self.parentView.addSubview(self.floatButton)

        self.contentView = UIView(frame: bounds)
        self.blurVisualEffect = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight))
        self.blurVisualEffect.frame = self.contentView.frame
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.blurVisualEffect)

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ActionButton.backgroundTapped(_:)))
        self.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        self.installConstraints()
    }

    required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    //MARK: - Set Methods
    open func setTitle(_ title: String?, forState state: UIControlState) {
        floatButton.setImage(nil, for: state)
        floatButton.setTitle(title, for: state)
        floatButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 8, right: 0)
    }

    open func setImage(_ image: UIImage?, forState state: UIControlState) {
        setTitle(nil, forState: state)
        floatButton.setImage(image, for: state)
        floatButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
        floatButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }

    //MARK: - Auto Layout Methods
    /**
        Install all the necessary constraints for the button. By the default the button will be placed at 15pts from the bottom and the 15pts from the right of its *parentView*
    */
    fileprivate func installConstraints() {
        let views: [String: UIView] = ["floatButton":self.floatButton, "parentView":self.parentView]
        let width = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[floatButton(\(floatButtonRadius))]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: views)
        let height = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[floatButton(\(floatButtonRadius))]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: views)
        self.floatButton.addConstraints(width)
        self.floatButton.addConstraints(height)

        let trailingSpacing = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[floatButton]-15-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: views)
        let bottomSpacing = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[floatButton]-15-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: views)
        self.parentView.addConstraints(trailingSpacing)
        self.parentView.addConstraints(bottomSpacing)
    }

    //MARK: - Button Actions Methods
    @objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIControl) {
        animatePressingWithScale(1.0)

        if let unwrappedAction = self.action {
            unwrappedAction(self)
        }
    }

    @objc func buttonTouchDown(_ sender: UIButton) {
        animatePressingWithScale(0.9)
    }

    //MARK: - Gesture Recognizer Methods
    @objc func backgroundTapped(_ gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if self.active {
            self.toggle()
        }
    }

    //MARK: - Custom Methods
    /**
        Presents or hides all the ActionButton's actions
    */
    open func toggleMenu() {
        self.placeButtonItems()
        self.toggle()
    }

    //MARK: - Action Button Items Placement
    /**
        Defines the position of all the ActionButton's actions
    */
    fileprivate func placeButtonItems() {
        if let optionalItems = self.items {
            for item in optionalItems {
                item.view.center = CGPoint(x: self.floatButton.center.x - 83, y: self.floatButton.center.y)
                item.view.removeFromSuperview()

                self.contentView.addSubview(item.view)
            }
        }
    }

    //MARK - Float Menu Methods
    /**
        Presents or hides all the ActionButton's actions and changes the *active* state
    */
    fileprivate func toggle() {
        self.animateMenu()
        self.showBlur()

        self.active = !self.active
        self.floatButton.backgroundColor = self.active ? backgroundColorSelected : backgroundColor
        self.floatButton.isSelected = self.active
    }

    fileprivate func animateMenu() {
        let rotation = self.active ? 0 : CGFloat(M_PI_4)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 0.1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.allowAnimatedContent, animations: {

            if self.floatButton.imageView?.image == nil {
                self.floatButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotation)
            }

            self.showActive(false)
        }, completion: {completed in
            if self.active == false {
                self.hideBlur()
            }
        })
    }

    fileprivate func showActive(_ active: Bool) {
        if self.active == active {
            self.contentView.alpha = 1.0

            if let optionalItems = self.items {
                for (index, item) in optionalItems.enumerated() {
                    let offset = index + 1
                    let translation = self.itemOffset * offset
                    item.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: CGFloat(translation))
                    item.view.alpha = 1
                }
            }
        } else {
            self.contentView.alpha = 0.0

            if let optionalItems = self.items {
                for item in optionalItems {
                    item.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
                    item.view.alpha = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fileprivate func showBlur() {
        self.parentView.insertSubview(self.contentView, belowSubview: self.floatButton)
    }

    fileprivate func hideBlur() {
        self.contentView.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    /**
        Animates the button pressing, by the default this method just scales the button down when it's pressed and returns to its normal size when the button is no longer pressed

        - parameter scale: how much the button should be scaled
    */
    fileprivate func animatePressingWithScale(_ scale: CGFloat) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 0.1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.allowAnimatedContent, animations: {
            self.floatButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Archivo ActionButtonItem.swift

```
import UIKit

public typealias ActionButtonItemAction = (ActionButtonItem) -> Void

open class ActionButtonItem: NSObject {

    /// The action the item should perform when tapped
    open var action: ActionButtonItemAction?

    /// Description of the item's action
    open var text: String {
        get {
            return self.label.text!
        }

        set {
            self.label.text = newValue
        }
    }
    /// View that will hold the item's button and label
    internal var view: UIView!

    /// Label that contain the item's *text*
    fileprivate var label: UILabel!

    /// Main button that will perform the defined action
    fileprivate var button: UIButton!

    /// Image used by the button
    fileprivate var image: UIImage!

    /// Size needed for the *view* property presente the item's content
    fileprivate let viewSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 35)

    /// Button's size by default the button is 35x35
    fileprivate let buttonSize = CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)

    fileprivate var labelBackground: UIView!
    fileprivate let backgroundInset = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)

    /**
        :param: title Title that will be presented when the item is active
        :param: image Item's image used by the it's button
    */
    public init(title optionalTitle: String?, image: UIImage?) {
        super.init()

        self.view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.viewSize))
        self.view.alpha = 0
        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        self.button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        self.button.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: self.viewSize.width - self.buttonSize.width, y: 0), size: buttonSize)
        self.button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        self.button.layer.shadowRadius = 2
        self.button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
        self.button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        self.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ActionButtonItem.buttonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        if let unwrappedImage = image {
            self.button.setImage(unwrappedImage, for: UIControlState())
        }

        if let text = optionalTitle , text.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces).isEmpty == false {
            self.label = UILabel()
            self.label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 13)
            self.label.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
            self.label.textAlignment = .right
            self.label.text = text
            self.label.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ActionButtonItem.labelTapped(_:))))
            self.label.sizeToFit()

            self.labelBackground = UIView()
            self.labelBackground.frame = self.label.frame
            self.labelBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.labelBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 3
            self.labelBackground.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
            self.labelBackground.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
            self.labelBackground.layer.shadowRadius = 0.2
            self.labelBackground.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

            // Adjust the label's background inset
            self.labelBackground.frame.size.width = self.label.frame.size.width + backgroundInset.width
            self.labelBackground.frame.size.height = self.label.frame.size.height + backgroundInset.height
            self.label.frame.origin.x = self.label.frame.origin.x + backgroundInset.width / 2
            self.label.frame.origin.y = self.label.frame.origin.y + backgroundInset.height / 2

            // Adjust label's background position
            self.labelBackground.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(130 - self.label.frame.size.width)
            self.labelBackground.center.y = self.view.center.y
            self.labelBackground.addSubview(self.label)

            // Add Tap Gestures Recognizer
            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ActionButtonItem.labelTapped(_:)))
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

            self.view.addSubview(self.labelBackground)
        }

        self.view.addSubview(self.button)
    }

    //MARK: - Button Action Methods
    @objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let unwrappedAction = self.action {
            unwrappedAction(self)
        }
    }

    //MARK: - Gesture Recognizer Methods
    @objc func labelTapped(_ gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let unwrappedAction = self.action {
            unwrappedAction(self)
        }
    }
}
```

Luego en el ViewController se crea y configura el botón de la siguiente manera.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var actionButton : ActionButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupButtons()
    }

    func setupButtons(){
        let google = ActionButtonItem(title: "Google", image: UIImage .init(named: "nombre-de-mi-icono-google"))
        google.action = { item in self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red }
        let twitter = ActionButtonItem(title: "Twitter", image: UIImage .init(named: "nombre-de-mi-icono-twitter"))
        twitter.action = { item in self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue }

        actionButton = ActionButton(attachedToView: self.view, items: [google, twitter])
        actionButton.setTitle("+", forState: UIControlState())
        actionButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 238.0/255.0, green: 130.0/255.0, blue: 130.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
        actionButton.action = { button in button.toggleMenu()}
    }
}
```

Saludos.